# Finding element in XML file - what if it's not?

Tags: python, excel, xml, loops, if-statement

I want to have a loop which is checking if element *"CompAttrVal name"* exist in XML file and if it is get element *"Value"* and if is not - setting the variable *"Value"* as empty.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root ReleaseDate="2022102110391995" StartDate="2022102110391995" EndDate="00" Version="1.0.0">
  <Type name="0204N01470-00" Desc="FA Porsche 992 TOP RHD S2" OID="174188" SrcOID="174187" TID="3">
    <Component name="MachineTools" OID="177350" SrcOID="378" TID="8">
      <ComponentNo name="St53_DryTesting" OID="74902" SrcOID="74902" TID="19">
        <CompAttrVal name="TesterECUPlugMirror" OID="74903" SrcOID="74903" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="0"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="TesterECUPlugAngle" OID="74904" SrcOID="74904" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="0"></CompAttrVal>
      </ComponentNo>
      <ComponentNo name="St73_FirewallGasket" OID="74906" SrcOID="74906" TID="19">
        <CompAttrVal name="Mounting" OID="74907" SrcOID="74907" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="YES"></CompAttrVal>
      </ComponentNo>
    </Component>
    <Component name="Pos010_GearHousing" OID="174253" SrcOID="379" TID="8">
      <ComponentNo name="0204842158" OID="4485" SrcOID="4485" TID="19">
        <CompAttrVal name="GearHousingDesign" OID="4545" SrcOID="4545" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="standard"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="TieRodDistance" OID="4546" SrcOID="4546" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="100"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="NumberOfStuds" OID="4547" SrcOID="4547" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="2"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="StudPos22X" OID="4548" SrcOID="4548" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="-13,17"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="StudPos22Y" OID="4549" SrcOID="4549" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="-49,17"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="StudPos24X" OID="4550" SrcOID="4550" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="13,17"></CompAttrVal>
        <CompAttrVal name="StudPos24Y" OID="4551" SrcOID="4551" TID="10" DataType="String" Value="49,17"></CompAttrVal>
      </ComponentNo>
    </Component>
```

**Options - what the XML file could have:**

1. CompAttrVal name="StudPos22X", "StudPos22Y", "StudPos24X" and "StudPos24Y"
2. CompAttrVal name="StudPos21X", "StudPos21Y", "StudPos23X" and "StudPos23Y"
3. or all of them: CompAttrVal name="StudPos21X", "StudPos21Y", "StudPos22X", "StudPos22Y", "StudPos23X", "StudPos23Y", "StudPos24X" and "StudPos24Y"

**Code:**

```
def get_data_from_xml(path):
    #print(path)
    
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for Type in root.iter('Type'):
        PN = Type.get('name')
        #print(f"Part number: {PN}")
        DS = Type.get('Desc')
        #print(f"Description: {DS}")
        
        for Component in root.iter('Component'):
            CName = Component.get('name')
            if CName == 'Pos010_GearHousing':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    GH = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Gear Housing: {GH}")   
                    for CompAttrVal in Component.iter('CompAttrVal'):
                        GH_AttrVal = CompAttrVal.get('name') 
                        if GH_AttrVal == 'GearHousingDesign':
                            GH_Design = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_Design == 'mirrored':
                                GH_Design_standard = ''
                                GH_Design_mirrored = 'x'
                            elif GH_Design == 'standard':
                                GH_Design_standard = 'x'
                                GH_Design_mirrored = ''
                        #GH - ZAM?
                        elif GH_AttrVal == 'TieRodDistance':
                            GH_Distance = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_Distance == '100':
                                GH_Distance100 = 'x'
                                GH_Distance101 = ''
                            elif GH_Distance == '101.8':
                                GH_Distance100 = ''
                                GH_Distance101 = 'x'
                        #GH - Riveting Progrs?
                        elif GH_AttrVal == 'NumberOfStuds':
                            GH_Studs = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            
                        if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos21X':
                            GH_Pos21X = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos21Y':
                                GH_Pos21Y = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                        else:
                            GH_Pos21X = ''
                            GH_Pos21Y = ''
                        
                        if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos22X':
                            GH_Pos22X = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos22Y':
                                GH_Pos22Y = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                        else:
                            GH_Pos22X = ''
                            GH_Pos22Y = ''

                        if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos23X':
                            GH_Pos23X = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos23Y':
                                GH_Pos23Y = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                        else:
                            GH_Pos23X = ''
                            GH_Pos23Y = ''
                            
                        if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos24X':
                            GH_Pos24X = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                            if GH_AttrVal == 'StudPos24Y':
                                GH_Pos24Y = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                        else:
                            GH_Pos24X = ''
                            GH_Pos24Y = ''

            if CName == 'Pos058_PowerPack':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    PP = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Power Pack: {PP}")
                    
            if CName == 'Pos082_PedalInterface':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    PI = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    #print(f"Pedal Interface: {PI}")
                                
            if CName == 'MachineTools':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    MT = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    if MT == 'St53_DryTesting':
                         for CompAttrVal in Component.iter('CompAttrVal'):
                            MT_St53 = CompAttrVal.get('name')
                            if MT_St53 == 'TesterECUPlugMirror':
                                MT_St53Mirror = CompAttrVal.get('Value') 
                                #print(f"Mirror: {MT_St53Mirror}")
                            elif MT_St53 == 'TesterECUPlugAngle':
                                MT_St53Angle = CompAttrVal.get('Value')
                                #print(f"Angle: {MT_St53Angle}")           
                    #St. 65 CamCheck???
                    elif MT == 'St73_FirewallGasket':
                        for CompAttrVal in Component.iter('CompAttrVal'):
                            MT_St73 = CompAttrVal.get('name')
                            if MT_St73 == 'Mounting':
                                global MT_St73Mounting
                                MT_St73Mounting = CompAttrVal.get('Value') 
                                #print(f"St73: {MT_St73Mounting}")
            
            if CName == 'Pos088_FirewallGasket':
                for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    Pos088 = ComponentNo.get('name')
                    if Pos088 == 'MountingPosition':
                        for CompAttrVal in Component.iter('CompAttrVal'):
                            TLA = CompAttrVal.get('name')
                            if TLA == 'ToolLifterAngle':
                                global MT_TLA
                                MT_TLA = CompAttrVal.get('Value') 
                             
    if(len(GH_Pos21X) != 0) and  (len(GH_Pos23X) != 0):
        #global GH_Typgruppe_21_23
        GH_Typgruppe_21_23 = 'x'
        GH_Typgruppe_22_24 = ''
        GH_Typgruppe_21_24 = ''
    elif(len(GH_Pos22X) != 0) and  (len(GH_Pos24X) != 0):
        #global GH_Typgruppe_22_24
        GH_Typgruppe_21_23 = ''
        GH_Typgruppe_22_24 = 'x'
        GH_Typgruppe_21_24 = ''
    elif(len(GH_Pos21X) != 0) and  (len(GH_Pos22X) != 0) and (len(GH_Pos23X) != 0) and (len(GH_Pos23X) != 0):
        #global GH_Typgruppe_21_24
        GH_Typgruppe_21_23 = ''
        GH_Typgruppe_22_24 = ''
        GH_Typgruppe_21_24 = 'x'
    
    #print(PN, GH, PP, DS, PI)
    return PN, GH, GH_Design_standard, GH_Design_mirrored, GH_Distance100, GH_Distance101, GH_Studs, GH_Typgruppe_21_23, GH_Typgruppe_22_24, GH_Typgruppe_21_24, GH_Pos21X, GH_Pos21Y, GH_Pos22X, GH_Pos22Y, GH_Pos23X, GH_Pos23Y, GH_Pos24X, GH_Pos24Y, PP, DS, PI, MT_St53Mirror, MT_St53Angle, MT_St73Mounting, MT_TLA

pn_list = []
gh_list = []
GH_Design_standard_list = []
GH_Design_mirrored_list = []
GH_ZAM_list = []
GH_Distance100_list = []
GH_Distance101_list = []
GH_RivProg_BTR1_list = []
GH_RivProg_BTR2_list = []
GH_Studs_list = []
GH_Typgruppe_21_23_list = []
GH_Typgruppe_22_24_list = []
GH_Typgruppe_21_24_list = []
GH_Pos21X_list = []
GH_Pos21Y_list = []
GH_Pos22X_list = []
GH_Pos22Y_list = []
GH_Pos23X_list = []
GH_Pos23Y_list = []
GH_Pos24X_list = []
GH_Pos24Y_list = []
pp_list = []
ds_list = []
pi_list = []
MT_St53Mirror_list = []
MT_St53Angle_list = []
MT_St65Gasket_list = []
MT_St65Spacer_list = []
MT_St73Mounting_list = []
MT_TLA_list = []

#generowanie DF
path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if '.' not in filename:
        if 'MASTER' not in filename:
            if 'GHOST' not in filename: 
                fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
                #print(fullname)
                PN, GH, GH_Design_standard, GH_Design_mirrored, GH_Distance100, GH_Distance101, GH_Studs, GH_Typgruppe_21_23, GH_Typgruppe_22_24, GH_Typgruppe_21_24, GH_Pos21X, GH_Pos21Y, GH_Pos22X, GH_Pos22Y, GH_Pos23X, GH_Pos23Y, GH_Pos24X, GH_Pos24Y, PP, DS, PI, MT_St53Mirror, MT_St53Angle, MT_St73Mounting, MT_TLA = get_data_from_xml(fullname)
                #print(pn, gh, pp)
                pn_list.append(PN)
                gh_list.append(GH)
                GH_Design_standard_list.append(GH_Design_standard)
                GH_Design_mirrored_list.append(GH_Design_mirrored)
                #GH ZAM??
                GH_Distance100_list.append(GH_Distance100)
                GH_Distance101_list.append(GH_Distance101)
                #GH Riveting Progs?
                GH_Studs_list.append(GH_Studs)
                GH_Typgruppe_21_23_list.append(GH_Typgruppe_21_23)
                GH_Typgruppe_22_24_list.append(GH_Typgruppe_22_24)
                GH_Typgruppe_21_24_list.append(GH_Typgruppe_21_24)
                GH_Pos21X_list.append(GH_Pos21X)
                GH_Pos21Y_list.append(GH_Pos21Y)
                GH_Pos22X_list.append(GH_Pos22X)
                GH_Pos22Y_list.append(GH_Pos22Y)
                GH_Pos23X_list.append(GH_Pos23X)
                GH_Pos23Y_list.append(GH_Pos23Y)
                GH_Pos24X_list.append(GH_Pos24X)
                GH_Pos24Y_list.append(GH_Pos24Y)
                pp_list.append(PP)
                ds_list.append(DS)
                pi_list.append(PI)
                MT_St53Mirror_list.append(MT_St53Mirror)
                MT_St53Angle_list.append(MT_St53Angle)
                #St. 65 CamCheck???
                MT_St73Mounting_list.append(MT_St73Mounting)
                MT_TLA_list.append(MT_TLA)
                
a = {'Description': ds_list,
     'Part number': pn_list,
     'Gear Housing': gh_list,
     'Power Pack': pp_list,
     'Pedal Interface': pi_list,
     'ECU PlugMirror': MT_St53Mirror_list,
     'ECU PlugAngle': MT_St53Angle_list,
     'CamProg_Gasket': MT_St65Gasket_list,
     'CamProg_Spacer': MT_St65Spacer_list,
     'Mounting ?': MT_St73Mounting_list,
     'MountingPosition/ToolLifterAngle': MT_TLA_list,
     'Standard': GH_Design_standard_list,
     'Mirrored': GH_Design_mirrored_list,
     'ZAM': GH_ZAM_list,
     '100 Bore Distance': GH_Distance100_list,
     '101,8 Bore Distance': GH_Distance101_list,
     'Program BTR 1': GH_RivProg_BTR1_list,
     'Program BTR 2': GH_RivProg_BTR2_list,
     'Number of Stud Bores': GH_Studs_list,
     '2_Studs_RobPos_21_23': GH_Typgruppe_21_23_list,
     '2_Studs_RobPos_22_24': GH_Typgruppe_22_24_list,
     '4_Studs_RobPos_21_24': GH_Typgruppe_21_24_list,
     'X-Position_21': GH_Pos21X_list,
     'Y-Position_21': GH_Pos21Y_list,
     'X-Position_22': GH_Pos22X_list,
     'Y-Position_22': GH_Pos22Y_list,
     'X-Position_23': GH_Pos23X_list,
     'Y-Position_23': GH_Pos23Y_list,
     'X-Position_24': GH_Pos24X_list,
     'Y-Position_24': GH_Pos24Y_list,
     
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()

#zapis DF do pliku
df = df.set_index('Description', drop = True)
df.to_excel("C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki CSV/data_frames_from_xml_new.xlsx", startrow=3, freeze_panes=(5,5))

#wczytywanie pliku do edycji
wb = load_workbook(filename = "C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki CSV/data_frames_from_xml_new.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

#filtrowanie
ws.insert_rows(5)
sheet.auto_filter.ref = "A5:DE300"

#zapis sformatowanego pliku do .xlsx
wb.save("C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki CSV/data_frames_from_xml_formatted_new.xlsx")
#df.head(10)
```

So as you can see I have a if/elif loop, but I know it is completely wrong, because I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18568/3904363937.py in <module>
     38                 fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
     39                 #print(fullname)
---> 40                 PN, GH, GH_Design_standard, GH_Design_mirrored, GH_Distance100, GH_Distance101, GH_Studs, GH_Typgruppe_21_23, GH_Typgruppe_22_24, GH_Typgruppe_21_24, GH_Pos21X, GH_Pos21Y, GH_Pos22X, GH_Pos22Y, GH_Pos23X, GH_Pos23Y, GH_Pos24X, GH_Pos24Y, PP, DS, PI, MT_St53Mirror, MT_St53Angle, MT_St73Mounting, MT_TLA = get_data_from_xml(fullname)
     41                 #print(pn, gh, pp)
     42                 pn_list.append(PN)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18568/2804858189.py in get_data_from_xml(path)
    130 
    131     #print(PN, GH, PP, DS, PI)
--> 132     return PN, GH, GH_Design_standard, GH_Design_mirrored, GH_Distance100, GH_Distance101, GH_Studs, GH_Typgruppe_21_23, GH_Typgruppe_22_24, GH_Typgruppe_21_24, GH_Pos21X, GH_Pos21Y, GH_Pos22X, GH_Pos22Y, GH_Pos23X, GH_Pos23Y, GH_Pos24X, GH_Pos24Y, PP, DS, PI, MT_St53Mirror, MT_St53Angle, MT_St73Mounting, MT_TLA

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GH_Typgruppe_21_23' referenced before assignment
```

I would be grateful if someone could help or give me a clue how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a dictionary instead of single variables. Store the attributes you are interested in in a list or set:

```
attribs = {"StudPos21X", "StudPos21Y", "StudPos22X", "StudPos22Y", "StudPos23X", "StudPos23Y", "StudPos24X", "StudPos24Y"}
```

and then, when looping of your elements, create a dictionary and override any default values with values from the XML:

```
values = { x: None for x in attribs } # The dictionary
for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'): 
    name = ComponentNo.get('name')
    if name in attribs:
        values[name] = ComponentNo.get('value')
# Now append values to your other data structure
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your idea, then changed GH_Pos21X to StudPos21X and etc everywhere, but then I have an error: "name 'StudPos21X' is not defined"

Comment: Access it as values['StudPos21X'] (if values is your dict).

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean? What should I change in code?